# Getting the System Folders in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on a C++ project in VS 2010. I want to get the path of DESKTOP, I have write the following code which has been given in some tutorial.

```
 TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
 SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0,path,CSIDL_DESKTOP,FALSE); 
 printf("Path : %s",path);
```

but the above code just printed

> Path : C

kindly make correction in the above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_tprintf`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx

When a TCHAR string is passed to a narrow-string function (such as `printf`), the data will be read byte-by-byte, and when it reaches the first null character ('\0'), it will be interpreted as the end of string. This is why it only prints the first character of the TCHAR string.

`_tprintf` looks at one `TCHAR` at a time, so it will keep on looking until it hits a TCHAR that is zero.

Comment: This explains why it outputs only a 'C' -- path is a wide char and 2nd byte is a 0; thus terminating the string early.

Answer (score 2):

I think your project had a charset 'Unicode' in settings.
In this case, TCHAR was treated as wchar_t, and SHGetSpecialFolderPath was defined as SHGetSpecialFolderPathW, so, the path of 'DESKTOP' you got was in Unicode, so you have two choices to solve this problem.

1. 1.use 'printf("%S")' with a upper-case 'S' other than lower-case 's' to print your path.
2. 2.use 'wprintf("%s")' with a lower-case 's' other than upper-case 'S' to print your path.

That is to say, you can print opposite char(char/wchar_t) with a opposite-case 'S' or 's'.
I'm glad may be i can help you!
Oh, i forgot to explan the output.
In your code, path was wchar_t, but '%s' with a lower-case 's', your path was treated as char by 'printf'.

The wchar_t data(16 bits) in your path like this:

{L'C', L'\', L'W', L'i', L'n', L'd', L'o', L'w', L's', L'\', .../*i.e.*/}

And the char data(also known as byte data, 8 bits) like this:

{'C', '\0', '\', '\0', 'W', '\0', 'i', '\0', .../*i.e.*/}

It was just looks like the string "C", because "\Windows.../**/" is behind a 'null-terminal' tag '\0', and it was ignored.